# "TypeError: ModalBuilder is not a constructor!" shows up when i run the code

Tags: javascript, discord.js, typeerror

I am new in programming and I started to code a Discord bot. The last command that I wanted to create was an embed builder with a Modal which is when I got the error. Maybe it is because of the following line:

```js
        if (interaction.commandName === 'embed'){
```

but I am not sure about it.

My `index.js`:

```js
require("dotenv").config()
const fs = require("fs")
const { Client, Collection, interaction, ModalBuilder } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({intents: []})
client.commands = new Collection()

//const prefix = (process.env.PREFIX);

client.once("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${client.user.tag}! I'm on ${client.guilds.cache.size} guild(s)!`)
    client.user.setActivity({name: "Bot by Keanu", type: "PLAYING"})
})

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync("./src/commands").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"))

commandFiles.forEach(commandFile => {
    const command = require(`./commands/${commandFile}`)
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command)
})

client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
    if(!interaction.isCommand()) return
    
    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName)

    if(command) {

        try {
            await command.execute(interaction)
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error)

            if(interaction.deferred || interaction.replied) {
                interaction.editReply("Fehler")
            }else
            interaction.reply("Fehler")
        }
    }
})



client.login(process.env.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN)
```

My `modal-embed.js`:

```js
const { ActionRow } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { TextInputStyle, InteractionType } = require('discord-api-types/v10');
const {  interaction, ActionRowBuilder, ModalBuilder, Interaction } = require('discord.js');
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders")
const { ModalBuilder } = require('@discordjs/modals')


module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder().setName("embed").setDescription("Embed Creator"),
    async execute(interaction) {
        if (interaction.commandName === 'embed'){
        const modal = new ModalBuilder()
            .setCustomId("embedModal")
            .setTitle("Embed Erstellen")
        
        const titleInput = new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId("title")
            .setLable("Titel")
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
            .setPlaceholder("Titel")

        const descriptionInput = new TextInputBuilder()
        .setCustomId("description")
        .setLable("Beschreibung")
        .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Paragraph)
        .setPlaceholder("Beschreibung")
        //.setRequired(false)
        //.setMinLength(2)
        //.setMaxLength(100)

        const authorInput = new TextInputBuilder()
        .setCustomId("author")
        .setLable("Autor")
        .setPlaceholder("Autor")
        .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
        .setValue(interaction.user.username)

        modal.addComponents([
            new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(titleInput),
            new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(descriptionInput),
            new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(authorInput)
            //new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(titleInput),
            //new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(titleInput)
        ])
        await interaction.showModal(modal)
        }
    }
}
```

And the error which I get:

```js
TypeError: ModalBuilder is not a constructor
    at Object.execute (D:\Pc\bot-dc\src\commands\modal-embed.js:12:23)
    at Client.<anonymous> (D:\Pc\bot-dc\src\index.js:30:27)
    at Client.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (D:\Pc\bot-dc\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:83:12)
    at Object.module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (D:\Pc\bot-dc\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (D:\Pc\bot-dc\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:346:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (D:\Pc\bot-dc\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:482:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (D:\Pc\bot-dc\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:317:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (D:\Pc\bot-dc\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
```

Comment: What's your discord.js version? Why do you try to import something like `interaction` from discord.js?

Comment: Also if there is a longer error message in your console, please post the rest of the error as well. Having a stack trace helps enormously when debugging, it's possible that the problem isn't in that file

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I have the newest version of discord.js and I tried to import these things because I first used it for another project (I now removed it)

Comment: @isaac.g The complete Error is to long to post it in a Comment so I uploaded it on a Website: https://jpst.it/30M4d

Comment: @Keanu Thanks, but next time please edit into your original post (using the "edit" button just under your post). Anyway, after testing your code myself I was unable to reproduce the error, it worked fine for me. Try logging the ModalBuilder to see what kind of value it is. And as long as you're using a modern IDE, try hovering the import and checking if it's actually being imported from discord.js.